# How to inherit NSPanel in Python/PyObjC?

Tags: python, pyobjc

I'm porting a little library of Objective-C/Cocoa into Python/PyObjC.
And I'm confusing about the way to implement.

Original code starts like below:

```
@implementation HUDWindow
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect 
                styleMask:(unsigned int)styleMask 
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType 
                    defer:(BOOL)flag 
{
    if (self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect 
                                styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask 
                                  backing:bufferingType 
                                    defer:flag]) {
        // initialize code here
             :
             :
             :
             :
             :
             :
        return self;
    }
}
```

And in header file says that HUDWindow class inherits NSPanel.
As far as I read the code, initialize is progress like this:

1. HUDWindow's initContentRect overrides NSPanel's initContentRect.
2. Inside of HUDWindow's initContentRect, NSPanel's initContentRect is called and get the result as "self".

First, I write python code like this. It's a translation of word-by-word:

```
class HUDWindow(NSPanel):
    def initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(self, rect, style, buf, flag):
        self = NSPanel.initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(
            rect, NSBorderlessWindowMask, buf, flag)
        # initialize code here
             :
             :
             :
             :
             :
             :
        return self
```

It didn't work because `self` is only a instance of `NSPanel`. I can't call any addictional functions I've ported from original obj-c code.

So I changed my code like this:

```
class HUDWindow(NSPanel):
    def initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(self, rect, style, buf, flag):
        self.window = NSPanel.initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(
            rect, NSBorderlessWindowMask, buf, flag)
        # initialize code here
             :
             :
             :
             :
             :
             :
        return self.window
```

It worked a little better. At least, I could call other functions in this initialize function.
But outside of initialize function, I can't call other functions ported from original code.

So I tried like this:

```
class HUDWindow(NSPanel):
    def initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(self, rect, style, buf, flag):
        self.window = NSPanel.initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(
            rect, NSBorderlessWindowMask, buf, flag)
        # initialize code here
             :
             :
             :
             :
             :
             :
         self.window.setTitle_ = self.setTitle_
         return self.window
```

It didn't work. I can't overwrite or add functions after making instance.

Now I'm feeling that I'm doing totally wrong. Is there any common way to inherit a class like NSPanel or NPWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution is on the right path. In the second, you'd need to either use `NSProxy` or write your own explicit delegation, which is a pain (and the third isn't the way to do that—you *can* do something similar through swizzling, but don't).

However, there are a few problems.

First, this code:

```
self = NSPanel.initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(rect, NSBorderlessWindowMask, buf, flag)
```

… is equivalent to this ObjC code:

```
self = [NSPanel initWithContentRect:rect 
                          styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                            backing:buf
                              defer:flag]
```

… when what you want is:

```
self = [super initWithContentRect:rect 
                        styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                          backing:buf
                            defer:flag]
```

The PyObjC equivalent of the latter is:

```
self = super().initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(rect, NSBorderlessWindowMask, buf, flag)
```

Or, in 2.x:

```
self = super(HUDWindow, self).initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(rect, NSBorderlessWindowMask, buf, flag)
```

In ObjC, `super` isn't the superclass, but a special magic object which is effectively "self as an instance of the superclass". It's almost exactly like Python 3's `super()`, or the less-magical Python 2 `super`, and PyObjC does the extra work to mean you can ignore that "almost".

What you were doing was (trying to) initialize the `NSPanel` class object (or maybe the class object of the PyObjC bridge to `NSPanel`, I'm not sure which), or possibly even trying to initialize the `rect` as if it were an `NSPanel`. Whatever you're doing, it can't possibly do anything to initialize your `self` instance. (And assigning the result to `self` doesn't do the same thing in Python as in ObjC. It's still usually idiomatic style in PyObjC, but don't be misled by it; the only effect it has is if you use `self` again within the initializer method. At any rate, at best that would cover up the problem in ObjC, not fix it…) So, after returning from this method, your `self` is still the allocated but uninitialized `NSPanel` instance that it was before you called anything.

This is mostly explained pretty early in the tutorial, in [Two Phase Instantiation](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/core/intro.html#two-phase-instantiation).

Comment: Thank you @abamert! Your answer contains everything that exactly I want (and need) to know! I can't help saying "Eureka!".